# Getting output as 'Nan'

Tags: javascript

When i call this function on an event it would give me a output as 'Nan'. why is that?

```
function fillValue(id){
    var qty = Number(document.getElementById('quantity' + id));
    var price = Number(document.getElementById('price' + id));

    var total = Number(qty * price);
    document.getElementById('value' + id).value = total;

}
```

Comment: can you provide you html please.

Comment: You're trying to convert HTML elements into numbers instead of their content or value (in case of input fields).

Comment: Missing `.value` chained to `document.getElementById('quantity' + id)`? `document.getElementById('quantity' + id)` returns an `HTMLElement`

Comment: You're trying create a number from a HTML element, you should probably use `Number(document.getElementById('quantity' + id).textContent)` or `Number(document.getElementById('quantity' + id).value)`

Comment: <input type'text' class='form-control' id='quantity$count' onblur='fillValue($count)'>

Comment: thanks titus..it worked

Comment: @guest271314 Not technically chaining because `value` is a property -- it's not a function and doesn't return the instance of the element itself

Comment: @AndrewLi What is the proper technical description?

Comment: @guest271314 Just accessing a property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Nan` is "not a number"

`document.getElementById` return the HTML element. you cannot convert html element to  Number.

`document.getElementById('quantity' + id)` and `document.getElementById('price' + id` These are `Nan`. You are trying to multiple `NaN`, so you get `NaN`.

If it's `input` you can get its value by using `document.getElementById('quantity' + id).value`

Your code will look like this

```
function fillValue(id){
    const qty = Number(document.getElementById('quantity' + id).value);
    const price = Number(document.getElementById('price' + id).value);

    const total = qty * price;
    document.getElementById('value' + id).value = total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss `.value` for qty and price variable:

```
    function fillValue(id){
    var qty = Number(document.getElementById('quantity' + id).value);
    var price = Number(document.getElementById('price' + id).value);

    var total = Number(qty * price);
    document.getElementById('value' + id).value = total;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the content of an element to integer.

```
function fillValue(id){
    var qty = document.getElementById('quantity' + id);
    var price = document.getElementById('price' + id);

    //parse to number
    qty = parseInt(qty);
    price = parseInt(price);

    var total = (qty * price);
    document.getElementById('value' + id).value = total;

}
```